# How to build many different packages with CMake

Tags: c++, cmake

I'm trying to put together a CMake project where I have different packages that I need to build. This is my desired structure:

```
package1
  src
    file.cpp
  test
    file_test.cpp
package2
  src
    file2.cpp
  test
    file2_test.cpp
CMakeLists.txt
main.cpp // this will be removed later
```

This is my current **CMakeLists.txt** file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)

# set the project name
project(cppApp)

# specify the C++ standard
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED True)

include_directories(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR})

# add the executable
add_executable(cppApp main.cpp ./package1/src/file.cpp ./package2/src/file2.cpp)
```

So the question is firstly, is a library considered a package in CMake? This question comes from someone who have done a lot of Java where I would typically call that a package and not a library. But does it in CMake?

Also, how do I in CMake include all files in the "packages" to be built instead of hard coding in the files as an executable? If I create many .cpp/.h files I want to automate this as much as possible.

I have seen that some other projects use a CMakeLists.txt file inside each "package", is this ideal? And is this good practice?

If you have a better suggestion according to some standard I should use to structure my project I would like to know a good one as well.

Comment: Can you please elaborate about the _"package"_ term? It's completely unclear what is considered being one.

Comment: Package in Java is not a library, it's a way to organize classes into namespaces. They could be libraries or part of your own project. In C++ you use namespaces for the exact same purpose

Comment: Yes that I understand. That's why I wanted some clarification if in C++/CMake what the definition is and how I should think according to my structure and how to build it. CMake have something called `add_library(lib)` and is those kinds of directories considered a library? Can something nudge me in the right direction or show some kind of example how that differs and how to add that to a CMake file for it to build?

Comment: A package is a package, a library is a library; both aren't synonyms in C++ (and therefore CMake). A package in cmake terms has more in common with e.g. apt packages: One package may contain an arbitary number of executables, libraries, header files, ect. Note that this does indeed mean a header only library could be considered a package. As for creating a package in CMake: that would be done using `cmake --install ...`, `cpack` which work based on the `install` cmake command among other things but to me it seems like that's not what you're hoping to achieve right now.

Comment: you can use `file(GLOB SRC_FILES dir/*.cpp)` to automate listing of source files but there are performance issues, partially solved by `CONFIGURE_DEPENDS` keyword, not mentioning that you may list files which you do not actually want as part of

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So the question is firstly, is a library considered a package in
> CMake? This question comes from someone who have done a lot of Java
> where I would typically call that a package and not a library. But
> does it in CMake?

Your definition of package in Java is not quite accurate. Package is just a mean to organize classes in Java in namespace manner. It could be classes of a separate library, but nothing prevents you from using different packages within the same project. It has nothing to do with [CMake packages](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-packages.7.html), where each package is actually a whole separate project.

> I have seen that some other projects use a CMakeLists.txt file inside
> each "package", is this ideal? And is this good practice?

`CMakeLists.txt` files in subdirectories merely define new subset of rules for those directories. In order to make your CMake project respect those rules, you add such directory with `add_subdirectory`. It's not neccessarily a separate library, you can make subset of rules for parts of a single project, and it's usually a good idea to do that if some files are really that different.

> CMake have something called add_library(lib) and is those kinds of directories considered a library?

`add_library` creates so-called CMake target, just like `add_executable`. The targets can be linked with each other with use of `target_link_libraries`, and that will indeed be considered a library in terms of C++.